# Postgresql - Keep Order of a subquery using IN operator

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a Ranking of Actors who have made films in more than X languages, this is my schema:

```
actor( actorid, actorname)
act ( actoirid, movieid, as_character)
movie ( movieid, title, mvyear)
lang (movieid, lang)
```

And this is the query that I'm stuck with:

```
SELECT actorid, actorname, title, mvyear, as_character, lang 
FROM actor NATURAL JOIN act NATURAL JOIN movies_slice NATURAL JOIN lang
WHERE actorid IN (
    SELECT act.actorid FROM act NATURAL JOIN lang 
    GROUP BY (act.actorid) HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT lang.lang)  > $X$
    ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT lang.lang) DESC --<<< Want to keep this order.
)
```

I know that the order of a subquery on the right side of the IN operator is discarded. How can I workaround this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use `NATURAL JOIN`.  It is a bug waiting to happen.  The join keys are whatever column names that match -- it doesn't even follow declared foreign key relationships.  And, the query is hard to follow because you don't know what keys are used for joining.

Then, to do what you want, move the subquery to the `FROM` clause, calculate the count as a field, and order by that:

```
SELECT a.actorid, a.actorname, m.title, m.mvyear, act.as_character, l.lang 
FROM actor a JOIN
     act
     USING (actorid) JOIN
     movies m
     USING (movieid) JOIN
     lang l
     USING (movieid) JOIN
     (SELECT act.actorid, COUNT(DISTINCT l.lang) as numlangs
      FROM act JOIN
           lang l
           USING (movieid)
      GROUP BY act.actorid
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT l.lang) > $X$
     ) al
     USING (actorid)
ORDER BY al.numlangs DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the headsup about the Natural Join... Is the use of JOIN and INNER JOIN equivalent in this case ?

Comment: @MateusS.Vasconcelos . . . Yes.  Without any `FULL` or `CROSS` modifiers, a `JOIN` is an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I don't like to edit answers, but I want to warn you that you got some little mistakes in your Query. Like ambiguous alias for actor and act, and using movie_id (column inexistent) to join with movies. Furthermore this mistakes, the query isn't correct, I got a error: "common column name "actorid" appears more than once in left table". I Don't know where to fix it.   :(